# Getting text between anchor tags

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a label that I put a hyperlink into with the function:

```
Private Sub showLink(title As String, cost As String, asin As String)
    Label1.Text = (String.Format("<a href=\WebSite3\LinkDisplay.aspx?Title=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(title) + "&Price=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cost) + "&ASIN=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(asin) + " \>" + title + "/" + cost + "/" + asin + "</a>"))
End Sub
```

I want to gain access to the the string `title + "/" + cost + "/" + asin` in order to split it with `String.Split("/")`.

I'm getting an error when I just try `Dim fields As String() = Label1.Text.Split("/")`.

What function should I use to get just the text that is between the `<a>` tags?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: You seem to already have the distinct values in your code, where exactly are you trying to split them?

Comment: You also say you are getting an error - what error?

Comment: @mreyeros In a different function I need to get the value that asin was in order to parse through a text file to find which item has that asin# (asin is essentially an id#)

Comment: @Oded "System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$Label1$0="<a href=\WebSite3\Li...")."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using a label, use a HyperLink object. You can set its URL like this:

```
Private Sub showLink(ByVal title As String, ByVal cost As String, ByVal asin As String)
    Dim link As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format("WebSite3/LinkDisplay.aspx?Title={0}&Price={1}&ASIN={2}", title, cost, asin))
    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = link
    HyperLink1.Text = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", title, cost, asin)
End Sub
```

Then, you can read out the querystring value of the url like so:

```
Private Sub GetLinkAttributes()
    Dim url As New Uri("http://" & HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HyperLink1.NavigateUrl.ToLower))
    Dim fields As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query)
    Debug.Print(String.Format("{0} / {1} / {2}", fields("title"), fields("price"), fields("asin")))
End Sub
```

You were using backwards slashes in your sample code, that may have thrown the error you were getting (HttpRequestValidationException).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using a Literal control to do this, and not a label. Or, better yet, use some type of link control.

You haven't added a whole lot of detail since the first time you asked this, but as long as the control is a server control, you can get the text using `Label1.Text`.

Once you have the text, you still need to parse out the part you want. There's no real trick to this. You need to remove the parts of the text that you aren't interested in.

This last task would be *far* simpler if you used some type of link control because you could just look at the link text value.

Comment: How can I use server controls to get Label1.Text? Is it Server.HtmlDecode()?

Comment: No, you do it on the postback by referencing the control from C# code.

Comment: I've tried `Dim s As String = Label1.Text` and I get the error: `System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$Label1$0="<a href=\WebSite3\Li...").`

Comment: It wouldn't take you much effort to Google that error and see that you need a page setting to prevent it. Beyond that, I think my work is done here. It's not at all clear why you need this since you already know what the value is (you set it). And you've ignored all suggestions that you should be using a different type of control. It's a lot of work and you don't even seem very appreciative of it. Perhaps someone else will be more help.